# can't restore Android Studio window after minimise

Tags: lubuntu, android-studio, openbox, android-emulator

When I minimize Android Studio window I can't restore it. I have to use Alt+Tab to navigate to it. And it would be kind of disabled (the icon is 50% transparent). So I would navigate to some other app then to it.

How Can I fix this ?

System: Lubuntu 18.04 LTS

I had this issue my old laptop for months and now I have a fresh installation in a brand new laptop and the problem still exists.

Also I have a problem with the emulator. If I navigate away and return back It won't restore window, even with the previous work-around as it stays (transparent).

I have Intellij IDEA installed and it works fine. I say this because Android Studio is built above Intellij IDEA.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a IntelliJ IDEA bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-196425

Workaround:

1. In Android Studio goto: Help > Edit Custom Properties
2. At the end of file add:

```
suppress.focus.stealing=false
```

3. Restart Android Studio, the bug is gone!